# How to show only last 3 characters in paragraph?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

is there some method or some string method, to show only last 3 characters in string?

I always have 13 digits number but i need to show only last 3 digits
Thanks for every help

Comment: Use substring and before that convert it to a string. `props.number.toString().substr(-3)`

Comment: If the paragraph is always a number: `<p>{props.number % 1000}</p>`

Comment: Thank you so much, that's exactly what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var str = number.toString();
var last3digits = str.substr(str.length-3);
```

Comment: Yes, that's another way, thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You could do something like this:

```js
const num = 123456789;
const numAsString = String(num);
const lastThreeDigits = numAsString.slice(-3);
```

Answer (score 2):

`splice()`is your friend.

```
const get3 = () => {
    const paragraph = 1231123123578;
    const getLast = paragraph.toString().split("").length;
    console.log(paragraph.toString().split("").splice(getLast - 3, getLast).join(""));
  };
```

or `slice()`

```
console.log(paragraph.toString().slice(-3));
```

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about these functions